# How can hook some code before deleting a comment?

Tags: 7, hooks, comments

How can I add few lines of code before comments get deleted. there must be some hook or something by which we can do this. I am getting nothing relevant by Googling.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Strange enough, but there is no `predelete` hook present with Drupal 7 core, or even not provided by the [entity](http://drupal.org/project/entity) module.

However the good news is [Drupal 8 has this feature](https://www.drupal.org/node/1384064)!